# Change the background color of table row according to the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the status is open the background would remain white, so if the status change to closed, i'd like to make the background green.Any idea.Thank you

```html
<table border='1' cellpadding='25'>

<th>Status</th>
<tr><td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td></tr><br>
<tr><td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td></tr><br>
<tr><td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td></tr><br>
</table>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use drop-downs for status fields, to restrict what values can be entered? Anyway, have you tried adding a `change` event handler that tests the value of the field and reacts accordingly?

Comment: the whole table row background, include all elements in it

Comment: @nnnnnn,great idea ,thanks

Comment: Hi @Codezzz, you would be better off googling this. It is a fairly common requirement and you will almost definitely find some guide or tutorial that will held you learn. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `.change()` event to determine current text of select.
2. Use `.closest()` to get the `tr`

```js
$("select").change(function(){
$("option:selected",this).text().trim().toLowerCase() == "open" ? $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color","white") : $(this).closest("tr").css("background-color","green")

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' cellpadding='25'>

<th>Status</th>
<tr><td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td></tr><br>
<tr><td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td></tr><br>
<tr><td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td></tr><br>

</table>
```

Adding and removing class

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("white green")
  $("option:selected", this).text().trim().toLowerCase() == "open" ? $(this).closest("tr").addClass("white") : $(this).closest("tr").addClass("green")

})
```

```css
.white {
  background-color: white
}

.green {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' cellpadding='25'>

  <th>Status</th>
  <tr>
    <td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td>
  </tr><br>
  <tr>
    <td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td>
  </tr><br>
  <tr>
    <td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td>
  </tr><br>

</table>
```

Comment: Is there any way when i change the value between open and closed, the color would change dynamically between white and green

Comment: @Codezzz check the demo

Comment: @Codezzz i also added another sample.. it uses adding and removing class.. you can play around that sample

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Codezzz glad to help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/qf3b3b7p/

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() === 'open') {
      $(this).parent().css({
        'background-color': '#fff'
      });
    }else{
     $(this).parent().css({
        'background-color': 'green'
      });
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' cellpadding='25'>

<th>Status</th>
<tr><td><select><option value="open">Open</option><option value="closed">Closed</option></select></td></tr><br>
<tr><td><select><option value="open">Open</option><option value="closed">Closed</option></select></td></tr><br>
<tr><td><select><option value="open">Open</option><option value="closed">Closed</option></select></td></tr><br>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `change` event to check the [`selectedIndex`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) property to add/remove a class to the parent `td`.

Or to change to whole row color... Just target the parent `tr`, as in the below snippet.

```js
$("select").on("change",function(){
  
  var parent = $(this).parents("tr");
  
  ( $(this)[0].selectedIndex == 1 ) ? parent.addClass("closed") : parent.removeClass("closed");
});
```

```css
.closed{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border='1' cellpadding='25'>

<th>Status</th><th>Other</th><th>Something</th>
<tr><td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td><td>Other cell</td><td>Other cell</td></tr><br>
<tr><td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td><td>Other cell</td><td>Other cell</td></tr><br>
<tr><td><select><option value="">Open</option><option value="">Closed</option></select></td><td>Other cell</td><td>Other cell</td></tr><br>
</table>
```

Comment: It there's more column in the table row,is there any way to change all column to green color?

Comment: thank you very much for your help, really appreciate it